# How to remove a item in a list that repeats itself? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have this list `[1268857, 384269, 72468, 161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, in which I compute a log calculation on each value. So I first remove the zeros and then I get this list: `[14.05362705319161, 12.859098107153008, 11.190900364095901, 5.0814043649844631]` . But the problem is that the last list will repeat itself 7 times. Is there a way to stop it from generating itself over and over?

I've tried this:

```
for item in gy:
    if item == 0:
        gy.remove(item)
    if item < 0:
        gy.remove(item)
    if item == (item - 1):
        gy.remove(item)
```

Although it removes the next item that repeats himself, gives me also an error:

```
 ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you can use a `set()`

Comment: It's usually a very bad idea to remove elements from a list you're iterating through

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
gy = list(set(gy))
gy.remove(gy.index(0))
```